# In Knockoutjs, can we declare MULTIPLE ObservableArrays inside a SINGLE ObservableArray?

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

Those multiple ObservableArrays will be an individual element of that Single ObservableArray.

I Have two ObservableArrays like:

```
self.matrix= ko.observableArray([
       { matrixElement: "" /*I Want to put "self.Criteria" observableArray here instead of "matrixElement" */}
    ]);

//This is the observableArray to be included inside self.matrix
self.Criteria = ko.observableArray([
       { criteriaField: "" }
    ]);
```

Now what I want is, I want **self.Criteria** to be a member element inside **self.matrix** . . . Could You Please give me the syntax or the way to write the code that should achieve my goal.

I am a Newbee . . . So Spare My Mistakes :)

***EDIT:*** I have done the part where I put **criteria** observablearray into **matrix** observablearray. Now I want to access the **criteriaField** of criteria observablearray (which is inside matrix observablearray !!!) So how do I do IT?

Comment: to access it you do like you would do with a normal array.

Comment: thank you! I have done that too :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exacly what you want but is it that self.Criteria is undefind. Declare self.critera before self.matrix.